# Efficiency problems moving data from CSV -> excel cells

Tags: vba

I started VBA - programming 2 days ago and I'm having efficiency problems given my limited knowledge of VBA and EXCEL.

I'm moving data from *.CSV to .xlsm files*. The .CSV file i receive is structured as
`SHEET;COL;ROW;VALUE`.

This .CSV is then read to a multidimension array and populates an excel file with`wb.Worksheets(ARRAY(i, SHEET)).Cells(R,C) = ARRAY(i, VALUE)`

To my understanding, applying the array to a range of cells does not work, as there is no continuous surface to which i'm sending each individual .csv row.

What i've tried most of it can be seen below. I believe a big issue i'm having is the pass-through between VBA -> EXCEL for each .CSV row. Is there any way this can be done by bulk instead?

All types of comments about efficiency and general how-to in VBA is greatly appreciated!

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub imp_Data()
    '----------------------------File Dialog for data input-----------------
    Dim Valarr As Variant
    Dim fullpath As String
    Dim CSVSHEET As Integer, CSVCOL As Integer, CSVROW As Integer, CSVVALUE As Integer

    fullpath = [YOUR TEST FILE.CSV]
    '----------------------------Read rawdata----------------------------
    Dim RawData As String
    Open fullpath For Binary As #1
    RawData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , RawData
    Close #1

    '----------------------------Split rawdata into array-------------------
    Dim r As Long, Nrow As Long, Ncol As Long
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim lineArr As Variant, cellArr As Variant
    If Len(RawData) > 0 Then
        'Split each row in CSV to str array
        lineArr = Split(Trim$(RawData), vbCrLf)
        'Dim final array
        Nrow = UBound(lineArr) + 1
        Ncol = UBound(Split(lineArr(0), ";")) + 1
        ReDim Valarr(1 To Nrow, 1 To Ncol)
        'Split each col on delimiter ";"
        For r = 1 To Nrow
            If Len(lineArr(r - 1)) > 0 Then
                cellArr = Split(lineArr(r - 1), ";")
                For c = 1 To Ncol
                    Valarr(r, c) = cellArr(c - 1)
                Next c
            End If
        Next r
    Else
        Debug.Print "No data read"
        ' do more stuff
    End If

    '----------------------------Read Table positions-----------------------
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Ncol
        If UCase(Valarr(1, i)) = "SHEET" Then
            CSVSHEET = i
        ElseIf UCase(Valarr(1, i)) = "COL" Then
            CSVCOL = i
        ElseIf UCase(Valarr(1, i)) = "ROW" Then
            CSVROW = i
        ElseIf UCase(Valarr(1, i)) = "VALUE" Then
            CSVVALUE = i
        End If
    Next i
    'Turn off calculation and screen update for efficiency
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    '--------------------------------------------Send data to Cells----------
    Dim L As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
    L = UBound(Valarr, 1) - LBound(Valarr, 1) + 1
    For i = 2 To L
        If IsEmpty(Valarr(i, 1)) = 0 Then
            wb.Worksheets(Valarr(i, CSVSHEET)).Cells(Valarr(i, CSVROW), Valarr(i, CSVCOL)) = Valarr(i, CSVVALUE)
        End If
    Next i

    'Release ValArr memory
    ReDim Valarr(0)
    Erase Valarr

    'Reapply calculation/screen update
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

From tests with 1 million rows it takes 14 seconds to read data to array and 5+ minutes to move the data to their designated cell. So the issue in the code below is (what i believe)

```
For i = 2 To L
  If IsEmpty(Valarr(i, 1)) = 0 Then
      wb.Worksheets(Valarr(i, CSVSHEET)).Cells(Valarr(i, CSVROW), Valarr(i, CSVCOL)) = Valarr(i, CSVVALUE)
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Given that very odd schema, I think 14 seconds + (5+) minutes isn't so bad for 1 million cells. How on earth did you end up with such a strange structure? I can't imagine there is anyway to do this in bulk... or rather they way you are doing it now is "doing it in bulk".

Comment: Data can be extracted as either xlsx or  CSV. The positions to where the values need to be implemented (ROW-COL-SHEET) is determined in another software where it can be done more efficiently. 

But the XLSX template thats populated cant be changed.

Surely there must be some efficiencies to improve in this code?

Comment: You can paste a two dimensional array directly into cells as long as you  specify the range correctly. Given a(3,4) then Range("a1:d3") = a() is valid. Does this help?

Comment: Hi Haraassed dad, no sadly it does not.

There is a logic behind the cells that needs to be populated. But hard-coding all of the input cell ranges between formula cells would be a painstaking task.  I was hoping for some inefficiencies in my syntax

Comment: @Shawnty Welcome to SO for a bright entry.Congratulation for a clean &  efficient code & fully agree with @JNevill. However the brilliantly structured code attracted me to test it. It took me 8 secs to  convert to array and finishes writing to cells at around 60 secs to process 1000 K rows of random data distributed to 5 sheets randomly With keeping calculation etc on takes around 100 secs (using empty workbook). However I had to made 2 changes only `Dim I as long` to prevent overflow error & changed `Cells(Valarr(i, CSVROW)+0, Valarr(i, CSVCOL)+0)` as string value of the array caused error.

Comment: I think the biggest bottleneck here is just going to be that it must be single threaded. You have no choice but to iterate that file (whether as an array or reading line by line) and then interpret the sheet and range to write the value. That's just going to be slow no matter how you go about it. You *could* take this over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and see if those folks want to step through this line by line looking for changes that *may* help. I wouldn't hold my breath on squeezing more speed out of this though.

Comment: The only other option would be to run this through some other language that can produce excel spreadsheets where you might be able to get a little lower level then a vba script. But, again, it's still going to iterate, write, iterate, write, iterate, write 1M times.

Comment: @Ahmed AU Oh thanks, glad to hear as a beginner in VBA. I agree on the changes, will implement asap :)

JNevill Okay. Thank you for the comments, was hoping there was some kind of options to eliminate the need for 1-by-1.